# Perform sort function based on key of map in vespa

Tags: vespa

We want to perform soring based on keys in a map. We have a map field in vespa of the type <string, int>.
Can we perform sorting based on the key values in map?

Answer (score 0):

No, and and I don't think it's clear what it would mean.
Given two sets of keys for two documents, what's the right sort order?

Comment: We would be performing sort based on the key. For example - select * from sources * where true  order by map.key. it would be similar to performing  sort on a static field in document.

Comment: But each document has many keys.